# Trying to create an edit modal on my index page using rails and bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

So far I've been able to make a modal that will 'create' a facility from the index page when user clicks the 'add new facility' button. Now my problem is trying to do the same thing except I want the user to be able to edit their facility using a modal from the index page as well. At this point when I click my 'edit' button on the webpage it opens a modal, but it is still the 'create facility' modal and not the 'edit modal'. Here's code:

views\facilities\index.html.erb

```
    <h1>Facilities</h1>

    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Abbr.</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Message</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @facilities.each do |facility| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= facility.name %></td>
            <td><%= facility.abbr %></td>
            <td><%= facility.status %></td>
            <td><%= truncate(facility.message, :length => 60, :seperator => ' ') %></td>
            <td><%= link_to '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Edit</button>'.html_safe, edit_facility_path(facility) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-edit">Destroy</button>'.html_safe, facility, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>
    <div class="center" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 80px;">
      <!-- Future Modal Button -->
      <%= link_to '<button class="center btn btn-success btn-fac" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Add New Facility</button>'.html_safe, new_facility_path %>
      <!--<%= link_to '<button class="center btn btn-success btn-fac">Add New Facility</button>'.html_safe, new_facility_path %> -->
    </div>

    <!-- Create Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Facility</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="small-container">
              <%= simple_form_for(@facility) do |f| %>
                <%= f.error_notification %>

                <div class="form-inputs">
                  <%= f.input :name %>
                  <%= f.input :abbr %>
                  <%= f.input :status, collection: ["Open", "Close", "Custom"], selected: ["Open"] %>
                  <%= f.input :message %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                  <%= f.button :submit %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <!-- Edit Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="small-container">
              <%= simple_form_for(@facility) do |f| %>
                <%= f.error_notification %>

                <div class="form-inputs">
                  <%= f.input :name %>
                  <%= f.input :abbr %>
                  <%= f.input :status, collection: ["Open", "Close", "Custom"], selected: ["Open"] %>
                  <%= f.input :message %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                  <%= f.button :submit %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here's controllers\facilities_controller.rb

```
 class FacilitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_facility, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /facilities
  # GET /facilities.json
  def index
    @facility = Facility.new
    @facilities = current_user.facilities.all
  end

  # GET /facilities/1
  # GET /facilities/1.json
  def show
    @facility = current_user.facilities.find(params[:id]) rescue redirect_to(facilities_path)
  end

  # GET /facilities/new
  def new
    @facility = Facility.new
  end

  # GET /facilities/1/edit
  def edit
    @facility = current_user.facilities.find(params[:id]) rescue redirect_to(facilities_path)
  end

  # POST /facilities
  # POST /facilities.json
  def create
    @facility = current_user.facilities.new(facility_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @facility.save
        format.html { redirect_to facilities_path, notice: 'Facility was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @facility }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @facility.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /facilities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /facilities/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @facility.update(facility_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @facility, notice: 'Facility was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @facility.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /facilities/1
  # DELETE /facilities/1.json
  def destroy
    @facility.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to facilities_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_facility
      @facility = Facility.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def facility_params
      params.require(:facility).permit(:name, :abbr, :status, :message)
    end
end
```

Let me know if more information is needed, thanks.